# Filter, Validate, and Generate Redbean models programmatically

Tags: php, dynamic-loading

A while ago, I wrote my first [Composer Package](https://github.com/r3wt/RedBeanFVM). The purpose is to completely avoid the tedious work of filtering and validating user input then constructing the model. I have questions about multiple functions:

### 1. `autoload()`: an Autoloader

During the development process, I was shopping around, looking for instructions on how to write an autoloader. All of the solutions I found seemed overly verbose / complicated / innefficient. So I wrote my own, and it seems to work.

I'm wondering what your thoughts are on it:

```
/**
 * Autoloader
 * @param $class
 * @return void
 */
public static function autoload($class)
{
    $file =  __DIR__ . str_replace('\\','/', preg_replace('/'. __NAMESPACE__ .'/','',$class,1)) . '.php';
    if(file_exists($file)){
        include $file;
    }
}
```

### 2. `getInstance()`

I decided the library would be a singleton, to make retrieval of the instance possible regardless of scope.

```
/**
 * Retrieve the Singleton instance of RedBeanFVM
 * @return RedBeanFVM
 */
public static function getInstance()
{
    return (is_null(self::$instance) ? self::$instance = new self : self::$instance);
}
```

### 3. `__call()`

I wanted to make it easy for users to define their own custom lambda's for cases not covered by the library, like, for example, if you needed to query database, use a special regex, etc.

I also wanted to have "Locale" packs, that is, country specific filters.

Having this in mind, I overloaded call and used it to attempt to call a custom filter or a locale filter, throwing the exception at last resort. I think it's pretty nifty, but you may probably disagree.

```
/**
 * This magic method searches the list of user defined filters for a match. if none is found, an exception is raised.
 * @param callable $function
 * @param mixed $args
 * @return mixed 
 */
public function __call($function,$args = false)
{
    if($this->custom_filter_exists($function)){
        return $this->custom_filter_exec($function,$args);
    }
    if($this->locale_filter_exists($function)){
        return $this->locale_filter_exec($function,$args);
    }
    throw new \exception('RedbeanFVM ::  Method `'.$function.'` doesn\'t exist!');
}
```

### 4. `snake_case()`

Redbean likes for all columns to be snake cased. Rather than rely on Redbean to do this for me, I wanted to be able to do it in a predictable way. I think I was just so far down the rabbit hole when I wrote this, I'm not even sure how it works.

```
/**
 * Convert a key to snake casing before setting it to the bean.
 * @param string $property the key.
 * @return string
 */
private function snake_case($key)
{
    return strtolower(trim(preg_replace("/(_)\\1+/", "$1",preg_replace('/([^a-zA-Z_])/','_',$key)),'_'));
}
```

### 5. `configure()`

Being a singleton, the library comes preconfigured. To override the settings, you must use `configure()`.

```
/**
 * configure multiple configuration settings
 * @param Array $c
 */
public static function configure($c)
{
    if(!is_array($c)){
        throw new \exception('RedBeanFVM :: configureAll() expects an array! `'.gettype($c).'` given.');
    }
    foreach($c as $k => $v){
        if(isset(self::$config[$k])){
            self::$config[$k] = $v;
        }else{
            throw new \exception('RedBeanFVM :: configure() `'.$k.'` is not a valid configuration option.');
        }
    }
    //if settings changed on an instantiated instance, we must reinstantiate.
    if(!is_null(self::$instance)){ 
        self::destroyInstance(); 
        self::getInstance();
    }
}
```

### 6. `__construct()`

```
/**
 * Protected Ctor
 */
protected function __construct()
{
    $c = self::$config;
    $locale = '\\RedBeanFVM\\Locale\\'.$c['locale'];
    self::$locale_filters = new $locale();
}
```

Now, it gets a bit more complex, all filters are chainable. The desired use case of the library is as follows:

```
$bean = R::dispense('user');

$required = [
    'Name'=>'name',
    'Email'=>'email',
    'User_Name'=>['rmnl','az_lower'], //chaining multiple rules
    'Password'=>'password_hash'
];

$optional = [
    'username'=>'min' //min is the minimum validation/filter
];

(\RedbeanFVM\RedbeanFVM::getInstance())->generate_model($bean,$required,$optional,$_POST);
```

### 7. `generate_model()`

```
/**
 * Generate a RedBean Model
 * @param  RedBean_SimpleModel &$bean An instance of RedBean_SimpleModel
 * @param  Array $required A list of required keys and their rules (key=>rule) OR (key=>[rule1,rule2, etc.])
 * @param  Array $optional A list of optional keys. Exceptions are not thrown for optional keys. default empty array.
 * @param  Array $source An array of data where to look for the keys. Default is post
 * @return void
 */
public function generate_model( &$bean, $required, $optional = [], $source = $_POST)
{
    foreach($required as $k => $v){
        if(!isset($source[$k])){
            throw new \exception('Missing form value: '.ucFirst($k));
        }
        if(is_array($v)){
            $bean->{ $this->snake_case($k) } = $this->chain($v,$source[$k]);
        }else{
            $bean->{ $this->snake_case($k) } = $this->{$v}($source[$k]);
        }
    }
    foreach($optional as $k => $v){
        if(isset($source[$k])){
            if(!empty($source[$k])){
                if(is_array($v)){
                    $bean->{ $this->snake_case($k) } = $this->chain($v,$source[$k]);
                }else{
                    $bean->{ $this->snake_case($k) } = $this->{$v}($source[$k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### 8. `chain()`

```
/**
 * executes an array of filters on an input and returns the output.
 * @param Array $functions
 * @param mixed $input
 * @return string
 */
public function chain($functions,$input)
{
    foreach($functions as $callable){
        $input = $this->{$callable}($input);
    }
    return $input;
}
```

### 9. `custom_filter()`

Allows user to define custom lambda. I'm a guy of modest knowledge, so I don't know if the checks I give are sufficient enough.

```
/**
 * creates a named callable and adds it to $custom_filters array. useful for creating custom filters.
 * @param string $name the name to assign to the callable.
 * @param closure $callable the callback function.
 */
public function custom_filter($name,$callable)
{
    if(empty($name)){
        throw new \exception('RedBeanFVM :: custom_filter() An Invalid Name was declared.');
    }
    if(method_exists($this,$name)){
        throw new \exception('RedBeanFVM :: custom_filter() `'.$name.'()` is a built in method of RedBeanFVM and a custom filter of that name may not be declared.');
    }
    if(!is_callable($callable)){
        throw new \exception('RedBeanFVM :: custom_filter() Method `'.$name.'` isn\'t a valid callable!');
    }
    $info = new \ReflectionFunction($callable);
    if( $info->getNumberOfParameters() !== 1 || $info->getNumberOfRequiredParameters() !== 1 ){
        throw new \exception('RedbeanFVM :: custom_filter() Method`'.$name.'` declares an invalid number of arguments! only one argument is allowed!' );
    }
    self::$custom_filters[$name] = $callable;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This expression is needlessly too complex:

> ```
>     return strtolower(trim(preg_replace("/(_)\\1+/", "$1",preg_replace('/([^a-zA-Z_])/','_',$key)),'_'));
> ```

It replaces non-alphabetic and non-underscore characters with an underscore, and finally trim any messaging and trailing underscores. There are several unnecessary parentheses, and the `\\1` back reference is an unnecessary complication too. A simpler way to achieve the same thing:

```
return strtolower(trim(preg_replace("/__+/", "_", preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z_]/", "_", $key)), "_"));
```

---

In expressions like this, where there is an assignment in both branches of an if-else with a complex expression on the left hand side:

```
    if(is_array($v)){
        $bean->{ $this->snake_case($k) } = $this->chain($v,$source[$k]);
    }else{
        $bean->{ $this->snake_case($k) } = $this->{$v}($source[$k]);
    }
```

It's better to extract the complex left hand side to avoid code duplication, like this:

```
    if(is_array($v)){
        $value = $this->chain($v,$source[$k]);
    }else{
        $value = $this->{$v}($source[$k]);
    }
    $bean->{ $this->snake_case($k) } = $value;
```

Also, this if-else chain appears twice in the code. It would be good to move this code into a helper function to avoid code duplication.

---

As with any utility library, it should be spot-on, and that includes formatting too. I recommend adding more spaces around the parentheses and cuddly braces in your if-else chains. For example instead of this:

```
    if(isset($source[$k])){
        if(!empty($source[$k])){
            if(is_array($v)){
                ...
            }else{
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Format like this, which is slightly easier to read:

```
    if (isset($source[$k])) {
        if (!empty($source[$k])) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                ...
            } else {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```